# How to convert blob to integer in python?

Tags: python, endianness

I have some file with little-endian encoding bytes in it, I want to take `N` bytes, specify endianess  and convert them into a decimal number using python (any version). How to do it correctly?

Comment: You can probably use the struct module. How big is `N`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Endianness of integers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400012/endianness-of-integers-in-python)

Comment: `N` can be up to file size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use something like this:

```
int.from_bytes(byte_string, byteorder='little')
```

Comment: Ooooo I did not know that. +1

Comment: Ok, we have a solution for Python 3. How to do this for Python 2?

Comment: Using `struct` as @juanpa.arrivillaga has mentioned

Comment: @warchantua: I've posted some Python 2 code. It's not as pretty as the Python 3 version, but it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Harshad Mulmuley' answer shows, this is easy in Python 3, using the `int.from_bytes` method. In Python 2, it's a little trickier.

The `struct` module is designed to handle standard C data types. It won't handle arbitrary length integers (Python 2 `long` integers), as these are not native to C. But you can convert them using a simple `for` loop. I expect that this will be significantly slower than the Python 3 way, since Python `for` loops are slower than looping at C speed, like `int.from_bytes` (probably) does.

```
from binascii import hexlify

def int_from_bytes_LE(s):
    total = 0
    for c in reversed(s):
        total = (total << 8) + ord(c)
    return total

# Test

data = (
    (b'\x01\x02\x03\x04', 0x04030201),
    (b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08', 0x0807060504030201),
    (b'\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef', 
        0xefcdab8967452301efcdab8967452301),
)

for s, u in data:
    print hexlify(s), u, int_from_bytes_LE(s)
    #print(hexlify(s), u, int.from_bytes(s, 'little'))
```

**output**

```
01020304 67305985 67305985
0102030405060708 578437695752307201 578437695752307201
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef 318753391026855559389420636404904698625 318753391026855559389420636404904698625
```

(I put that Python 3 print call in there so you can easily verify that my function gives the same result as `int.from_bytes`).

If your data is *really* large and you don't want to waste RAM reversing your byte string you can do it this way:

```
def int_from_bytes_LE(s):
    m = 1
    total = 0
    for c in s:
        total += m * ord(c)
        m <<= 8
    return total
```

Of course, that uses some RAM for `m`, but it won't be as much as the RAM used for reversing the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3 (or 2), you can achieve this with the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library.

```
with open('blob.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(n)
```

Now, you unpack using the appropriate [format specifier string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). For example, big-endian int:

```
num = struct.unpack(">i",data)
```

Comment: `struct` is available in Python2 as well, isn't it?

Comment: @VPfB Yes. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#module-struct).